# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when making a post request using node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to send a POST request to my server using Node.js

```
function login(email, company_code, password){
var options = {
    hostname: '266fd57b.ngrok.io',
    path: '/v1/manager/sign_in',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
        'email': email,
        'company_code': company_code,
        'password': password
    }
  };
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (body) {
      console.log('Body: ' + body);
    });
  });
  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });
  // write data to request body
  req.write('{"string": "Hello, World"}');
  req.end();
  return true;
}
```

But I keep getting error:

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 266fd57b.ngrok.io 266fd57b.ngrok.io:443
```

I tried all the fixes found on the Internet but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god this is because I have not entered billing account for google.
Dialogflow needs a credit card number to work.